# Show that the closure of $\cup_{k\geq1}F_k(D)$ is compact in $\Omega$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-manifolds

$\Omega$ is a domain of holomorphy, $D=\{z \in C : |z|\leq1\}$.For an arbitrary series of holomorphic functions $F_k:D\to \Omega$,The closure of $\cup_{k\geq1}F_k(\partial D)$ is compact in $\Omega$. Show that the closure of ${\cup_{k\geq1}F_k(D)}$ is also compact in $\Omega$.

I have tried to consider this problem from the definition of a domain of holomorphy. However, I did not solve it.

Actually, I do not have any useful idea about this question.

So sorry for being a beginning learner, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of the definition, some characterisation of domains of holomorphy works better here. Have you heard of [holomorphic convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphically_convex_hull)?

Comment: Yes, I know that. But what should I do to use the condition that "the closure of $\cup_{k\geq1} F_{k} (\partial D)$ is compact"?

Comment: Define $K = \overline{\bigcup_k F_k(\partial D)}$. Think about how $\widehat{K}$ fits into the situation.